# Accessing a VBA object using C#

Tags: c#, vba, com, ole

I have some C# software controlling an application. The application can be natively called via VBA. The documentation says that it is implemented as an OLE automation server.

When my code was still 32 bit I used to use Interop.MSScriptcontrol and call the VBA commands using the `.ExecuteStatement()`. Here is an example

```
MSScriptControl S = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass();
S.Language = "VBScript";
S.ExecuteStatement("set obj = CreateObject(\"End_Application.Application\")");
S.ExecuteStatement("set Instance = obj.NewApp");
```

Executing these 4 lines would create a new instantance of the application and then I would send more S.ExecuteStatements() to control the Application. If I wanted the application to return a value I would use the `S.Eval` method.

Now I have to migrate to 64 bit. I found [CodeFluent's](https://www.softfluent.com/documentation/) `ScriptEngine` class. I am using the `Eval()` method but the Application is not creating a new instance.

Can you please either point me to the correct use of the `ScriptEngine` class or how I can call the object directly via C# to create the instance and pass data to the instance i.e. replicate the `S.ExecuteCommand()` method.

Is there a way to eliminating the scripting classes and call the object directly?

Comment: `dynamic obj =  Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("End_Application.Application", true)); dynamic Instance = obj.NewApp;`?

Comment: Can you create the VBA object in VBA and pass it to your C# code as a parameter?

Comment: It's not clear what "VBA object" you're trying to access. As far as I can tell you don't need a "VBA object", you need to create an instance of a plain COM object, and for that to look like `var foo = new Bar();` then you need an interop assembly for the COM type library involved. This is all about COM, nothing about VBA.

Comment: Yes, ditch the script engine, it makes it too hard to see why this code cannot work in 64-bit mode.  When you do it in C# then you get a decent exception.  A 64-bit app can't see the registry keys that the app's installer created.